# How to loop programatically through 'pages' in react-native-onboarding-swiper?

Tags: react-native, ecmascript-6

I'm getting data via graphQL and I'd like to be able to edit the 'pages' section in https://github.com/jfilter/react-native-onboarding-swiper from the headless cms itself. All examples are hard coded data.

The data I'm getting from the API are values that looks like this:

```
{
  {
    color: 'red',
    url: 'https://dummyimage.com/300.png',
    title: 'Title 1',
    subtitle: 'Subtitle 1'
  },
  {
    color: 'blue',
    url: 'https://dummyimage.com/400.png',
    title: 'Title 2',
    subtitle: 'Subtitle 2'
  }
}
```

The example below works, but it's hard coded. If I am to receive the data from an API, how do I loop using map() ?

```
import { Image } from 'react-native';
import React from 'react';
import Onboarding from 'react-native-onboarding-swiper';

        const allPages = [
       {
              backgroundColor: '#fff',
              image: <Image source={require('./images/circle.png')} />,
              title: 'Onboarding Page 1',
              subtitle: 'This is one',
        }
    ];


const Simple = () => (
    <Onboarding
      pages={allPages}
    />
);
```

I expect received json data to be displayed in the 'pages' section.
This way multiple 'pages' can be created from the incoming json data.

Comment: I think one solution could be to mutate 'allPages' by pushing new objects in it (using a for loop)

Comment: Something like: `pages={() => someArray.map((item, index) => { return (<View></View>)}}` at a guess?

Comment: Thank you @swonder but this isn't working. Can't nest a component in there, I believe it's waiting to have props instead.